# How to hide code from presentation, but not from inferencer?

Tags: fsreveal

In [FsReveal](https://github.com/fsprojects/FsReveal), is there a way to hide declarations from the slides presentation, but not from [type inferencer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/692088/608639)?  I want the F# snippet to compile correctly and have the tooltips but it isn't important to show every line.  I'm not seeing this in the documentation, but perhaps it's obvious from one of the projects it incorporates?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that by placing html tags around the content with `display: none` I could hide it.  I don't know if this is (basically) the easiest way.

```
(**
<div style="display: none">
*)

type IntList = Int list

(**
</div>
*)

let (t : IntList) = ...
```